# Position Images/Background Images Relative to Mouse

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I would like to know what an efficient way is to **animate positions of images (or background images) in relation to the mouse**. Take Github, for example:

https://github.com/thispagedoesntexist

**This is one hella sexy 404 page.**

I want to make an impact on my users, and this surely does so in my opinion.

**Questions**

1) How can this be done?

2) Just CSS? CSS & JS?

3) Lastly, any libraries for stuff like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was made with a jQuery plugin called [Plax](https://github.com/cameronmcefee/plax).

Comment: Impressive, they make it easy. So, I'm thinking that this is not currently feasible with pure CSS, correct?

Comment: I won't say it's not possible because I haven't tried, but it would be really difficult to emulate something like this with no JS.

Comment: Relative to the *mouse* would be impossible without JS, anyways, I suppose. Parallax scrolling is, on the other hand.

Comment: Yes, the mouse is where the difficulty arises.